# Custom block last on productpage Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, porto-theme, porto

I'm working on an Magento 2 webshop and I have implemented some code to show a custom block on the productpage. But it is showing before the Product Details / More Information (tabs).

In the file **/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml** in this

`<referenceContainer name="content">`

I have added:

```
<container name="custom.bnr" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="custom-bnr-html" after="product.info.details">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="bnr_product_info" after="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">product-block-1</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</container>
```

Somehow I cannot have it to be shown as the last element of the page. Somehow the div `main-product-detail` (with the tabs) is shown under the `column main` instead of inside it.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Magento 2.4.4
Porto Theme

** LATER EDIT: I Think I found the "problem". The Porto Theme is adding some JavaScript to take the Product Tabs out of the container and put it below, to make it full width. So I was able to resolve it!

Answer (score 1):

> **Try This Code**

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
    <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review" name="reviews.tab" as="reviews" template="Magento_Review::review.phtml" group="detailed_info" ifconfig="catalog/review/active">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">30</argument>
        </arguments>
        <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form" ifconfig="catalog/review/active">
            <container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Review Form Fields Before"/>
        </block>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

`<argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">30</argument>` **This line is used for sorting.**

Comment: Thanks, but I think I found the problem (see the original post)